# ORA-00905 : missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing an error message:

> ORA-00905 : missing keyword

I guess that it is related to the `case` expression listed below. Any suggestions to resolve it?

This is the code :

```
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 as CATEGORY1 else 0 end,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_ACC_NAM as NAME else ''  end,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 > 50000 then M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 as PL_CATEGORY  else 0 end,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_ACC_NAM as PLCATE_NAME else '' end,
```

Comment: `as CATEGORY1` should come at the end of your statement. Same for the rest of the columns.

Comment: wlat about else 0 ? thanks

Comment: I need to display it in case that the column does not match the condition. Anyway, I tried putting as CATEGORY1 and the others at the end of the statements but the error remains

Comment: @PatrickHofman The column alias `as CATEGORY1` needs to go after each `case` expression - not after the statement.

Comment: could you write an example for me ? thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name obviously that is what I meant.

Comment: Hmmm . . . There is no `SELECT` or `FROM` clause.  These are required in Oracle.  There is an extra comma on the fourth line.  And the `CASE` syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 else 0 end as CATEGORY1,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_ACC_NAM else ''  end as NAME,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 > 50000 then M1.M_GL_CAT_T24  else 0 end as PL_CATEGORY,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_ACC_NAM else '' end as PLCATE_NAME,
```

Answer (score 2):

```
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 else 0 end as CATEGORY1 ,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_ACC_NAM else ''  end as NAME ,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 > 50000 then M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 else 0 end as PL_CATEGORY  ,
case when M1.M_GL_CAT_T24 <= 50000 then M1.M_GL_ACC_NAM  else '' end as PLCATE_NAME,
```